# Date number javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'd like to make a smart name in our Automation Engine with Javascript which would show the last number of the year and the current week's number. Like this: 520

```
function f ()
{
var today = new Date();
var weekno = today.getWeek();
return weekno;
}
f ();
```

This is my co-worker's try. Any idea?

Comment: Sorry but there is no `Date.getWeek` function.

Answer (score 0):

get week

```
 var today = new Date();
 var weekno = today.getWeek();
```

get Year

```
 var weekno = new Date().getFullYear()
```

subtring its value like that

```
var str = "Hello world!";
var res = str.substring(1, 4);
```

and then combine both like that

```
var str1 = "Hello ";
var str2 = "world!";
var res = str1.concat(str2);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! However my scripting skill is as low as Tyrion in Game of Thrones sadly. How would my script exactly look like? I tried to play with these line but couldn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this please?

```
function f ()
  {
  var today = new Date();
  var year = today.getFullYear();
  var onejan = new Date(year,0,1);
  var weekno = Math.ceil((((today-onejan)/86400000+onejan.getDay()+1)/7));
  yearweek = String(year)+String(weekno);
  return yearweek.substr(3,3);
  }

f ();
```